# Javascript string template for reuse

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make something like

```
var stringUrlTemplate = home.url + '/data/[param1]/[param2]/' + endurl;
```

And than something like in some loop:

```
outputUrlItem = print(stringUrlTemplate, someVarialbe, someVariable);
```

Basically what C/C++ can do.

I cannot use "/data/${param1}/${param2}/" because a string is served by server separetly from JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/kvpy4wex/

Comment: Great thing! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use placeholder which can be replaced. Here is an example

```js
if (!String.prototype.format) {
  String.prototype.format = function() {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) {
      return typeof args[number] != 'undefined' ?
        args[number] :
        match;
    });
  };
}

var stringUrlTemplate = '/data/{0}/{1}/';
console.log(stringUrlTemplate.format('data1', 'data2'))
```

OR,

```js
function printf() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  var str = arguments[0];
  return str.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) {
    return typeof args[number] != 'undefined' ?
      args[number] :
      match;
  });
};

var stringUrlTemplate = '/data/{0}/{1}/';
console.log(printf(stringUrlTemplate, 'data1', 'data2'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This package allow reusable template literals - [reuse-template-tag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reuse-template-tag), maybe it can help, Here is example from their docs:

```js
const reuseTemplateTag = require('reuse-template-tag')

const template = reuseTemplateTag`
    - Hey ${1} How are You?
    - Are You ok ${1} ?
    - Yes, thanks ${'me'}!
`
console.log(
    template({
        1: 'Joe',
        me: 'Andy'
    })
)
// Or provide sequence of values with Array
console.log(
    template(['Joe', 'Molly', 'Susan'])
)
```